# Extend Laravel template functions

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

What is the best way to convert this:

```
<div id="{{ $stat->type }}-{{ 
    str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($stat->description))
    }}-chart">
</div>
```

into this:

```
<div id="{{getDivId($stat)}}">
```

I mean, I need to create functions to use inside a blade template, I found something that use `@` in the laravel documentation, but I don't want to use `@`, I wan to use `{{ }}`.

Comment: Laravel already has what you’re looking for: `{{ str_slug($stat->description) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to put this on my model if I don't have a lot of them. The `$appends` array adds it to each query.

**Stat.php**

```
protected $appends = array('div_id');

public function getDivIdAttribute()
{
  return $this->type .'-'
    .str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($this->description));
}
```

Then you can access it like this on your blade template.

```
<div id="{{ $stat->divId }}">
```

If you have a lot, you might want to look into using a [Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) class.